# Permission denied for urls paths Django + Apache + mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I have configured a Django application to be hosted in an Apache server using mod_wsgi. I have successfully opened the home page, but haven't been able to open other URLs.

For instance, if I try to access `/pop/`, it returns 403 forbidden error.

Here is my code:

#### urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from dashboard import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.NewView.as_view()),
    path('pop', views.PopView.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

#### wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


path = '/home/andremou/DashboardUnicamp/unicamp/unicamp'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

#os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'unicamp.settings')
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "unicamp.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

#### .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin [CENSORED]
DocumentRoot [CENSORED]
#ServerName [CENSORED]
ServerName [CENSORED]
#ServerAlias [CENSORED]
ServerAlias [CENSORED]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond [CENSORED]
RewriteCond [CENSORED]
RewriteRule [CENSORED]

Alias /dashboardteste/ /home/andremou/DashboardUnicamp/unicamp/unicamp/

# Executar o Django como usuario apache
SuexecUserGroup apache apache
#Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

    <Directory /home/andremou/DashboardUnicamp/unicamp/unicamp> 
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

# Certificados TLS/SSL
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/moodle.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/moodle.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/moodle_chain.crt

WSGIScriptAlias /dashboardteste /home/andremou/DashboardUnicamp/unicamp/unicamp/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess unicamp python-home=/home/andremou/DashboardUnicamp/my_env python-path=/home/andremou/DashboardUnicamp/unicamp
WSGIProcessGroup unicamp

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</VirtualHost>
```

The structure of my files:

```
home
|-andremou
|-DashboardUnicamp
|-my_env
|-unicamp
||-dashboard
| |-migrations
| |-static
| |-templates
| |-models.py
| |-views.py
||-unicamp
| |-settings.py
| |-wsgi.py
| |-urls.py
```

I have tried to configure the wsgi and .conf files, but had no success.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the 403 error page and the code for the PopView?  What happens if you change `path('pop', views.PopView.as_view()),` to `path('pop', views.NewView.as_view()),`?

Comment: Hi Nathan, I have just found the problem with the code. Apparently I had two 
Alias for my application:

Alias /dashboardteste/ /home/andremou/DashboardUnicamp/unicamp/unicamp/ 

WSGIScriptAlias /dashboardteste /home/andremou/DashboardUnicamp/unicamp/unicamp/wsgi.py

I just had to delete the first Alias and let the WSGIScriptAlias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone running into this problem I have solved checking this resource: https://serverfault.com/questions/555955/can-i-configure-apache-mod-wsgi-so-that-the-alias-url-path-is-not-stripped-befor

Apparently I had two Alias for my application:

```
Alias /dashboardteste/ /home/andremou/DashboardUnicamp/unicamp/unicamp/
```

And this one:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /dashboardteste /home/andremou/DashboardUnicamp/unicamp/unicamp/wsgi.py
```

For Django applications the correct Alias is managed by the WSGIScriptAlias.

So, I solved removing the following line from my .conf file:

```
Alias /dashboardteste/ /home/andremou/DashboardUnicamp/unicamp/unicamp/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<Directory /home/andremou/DashboardUnicamp/unicamp> 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks Razenstein! I have made the suggested change, but still could not access the url paths.